# Целочисленные типы данных

Tags: c, c++

Есть ip_address=188.65.55.254

Преобразуем его в unsigned long int 4byte целое число

int_ip=3158390782

Для каких целей,почему и как его преобразовывают в signed long int

int_ip=-1136576514

Comment: Вот вам простое правило. signed-тип имеет значения от `-X` до `X - 1`. unsigned-тип имеет значения от `0` до `2X - 1`. Если ваше чсило лежит в промежутке от `0` до `X - 1`, конвертация между signed и unsigned ничего не меняет. Если unsigned-значение лежит от `X` до `2Х - 1`, конвертация вычитает из него `2X`, и получается отрицательное значение в диапазоне от `-X` до `0`. Так сделано потому, что остальная часть диапазона уже «занята».

Answer (score 4):

Ну очевидно же - IPv4-адрес состоит из четырех байтов, следовательно любой адрес такого вида может быть представлен как 4-байтное целое число, что в принципе достаточно удобно.

```
188.65.55.254 == BC.41.37.FE == 0xBC4137FE == 3158390782
```

Вообще число, получаемое в итоге, зависит от типа переменной, в которой вы сохраните результат. Пример:

```
int first = 188, second = 65, third = 55, fourth = 254;

unsigned int uIntIP = ( first << 24 ) | ( second << 16 ) | ( third << 8 ) | fourth;
long long longLongIP = ( first << 24 ) | ( second << 16 ) | ( third << 8 ) | fourth;

cout << uIntIP     << endl; // 3158390782
cout << longLongIP << endl; // -1136576514
```

Comment: Меня интересует в signed long int int_ip=-1136576514, получается отрицательное число.

Comment: Оно отрицательное потому что старший бит равен 1

Comment: потому что у unsigned long int и signed long int разныед иапазоны значений. И одна и та же комбинация битов может представлять в них разные числа

Comment: Объясните математическим языком как получается отрицательное число, когда применять и в каких случаях применять unsigned int и long int.

Comment: @avdoshkin [почитайте](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) о битовом представлении чисел со знаками. А когда и как применять `signed` vs. `unsigned` - это уже произвол программера (в данном случае вас)

Comment: >Объясните математическим языком как получается отрицательное число, когда применять и в каких случаях применять unsigned int и long int

что значит "математическим языком"? Математика не оперирует понятиями "разрядности", в ней не существует байтов и тем более типов signed и unsigned int. Читайте про дополнительный код и представление отрицательных чисел в памяти компьютера. Это исключительно вопросы программирования, а не математики.